# Changing variables in java

Tags: java

In the following code,

```
int i = 1;
int j = i + 2;
int i = 2;
```

Would 'j' equal 2 after 'i' has been changed to 2 or would 'j' still equal 1?

Comment: They are different references. Therefore `j` won't change.

Comment: Why don't you try it out? You'd have your answer quicker than asking it here.

Comment: It would not even compile because you created two variables named `i` also the original value of `j` is 3 not 1.

Answer (score 3):

When you assign a value to *any* variable in Java, only that variable changes.

In addition, these particular variables are primitives, not reference types. Each variable holds a value, not a reference to an object that might be shared among variables.

Also, note @gtgaxiola's observation that this code will not compile because of the second definition of `i`. This can be addressed as follows:

```
int i = 1;
int j = i + 2;
i = 2;
```

Now, if your variables were references to mutable objects, you could assign two  references to the same object, and change that object through either reference.

```
ColorRGB a = new ColorRGB(0,0,0);
ColorRGB b = a;
a.r = 255;
```

Here, both `a.r` and `b.r` will have the value of 255, because both are referring to a field in the same object.

Answer (score 0):

Once you initialized `int i = 1` you cannot "reinitialize" it to 2. If you wanted to change i to 2 you would say `i = 2;` after the initialization. Also j = 3 since i+2 = 3. In your provided code j never equals 1. Play around with it and you will answer your own questions like this.

```
int i = 2;
int j = i + 2; // j is initialized to 3
i = 2;  // no need for declaring int since you did it above. The compiler  already knows its type
j = j - i; // 3-2
System.out.println("i = " + i) // prints 2
System.out.println("j = " + j) // prints 1
```